# creating and updating ms access mdb files with visual basic

Tags: vb.net

how can i create and update mdb [ access ] files in visual basic 2008..

and also if i have a dll library how can i get all of its syntax for using it in visual basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [one example](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/ado/msaccess.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Project + Add Reference, COM tab, select "Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security".  That gets you the ADOX namespace.  The docs [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677200%28VS.85%29.aspx), [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680934%28VS.85%29.aspx) has a specific example of creating a new database.

Beware that the JET database is desperately outdated, it was deprecated close to 10 years ago.  You'll have major problems keeping it running in the very near future.  There is no 64-bit version available.